# Using validateStatus on RTK Query baseApi

Tags: rtk-query

Our API returns a 200 for all responses and includes an `errorCode` field in the response. The [RTK Query docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#handling-non-standard-response-status-codes) show that you can use `validateStatus` on your individual queries for this use case.

But is there a way to bake that into your base API (`createApi`) so that you don't have to use it for each endpoint?

Or perhaps there's a way to wrap `injectEndpoints` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Not at this moment, but a PR to also be able to pass it as a `fetchBaseQuery` option would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in fact to wrap `fetchBaseQuery` as explained [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery).

Here's how I did it:

```
const baseApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'baseApi',
  baseQuery: async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    const result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
    const {
      data: { data, errorCode, message },
      error,
    } = result as typeof result & { data: MyApiResponse };
    
    if (error) return result;
    if (errorCode) {
      return {
        error: {
          data: undefined, // required by typescript
          status: errorCode,
          error: message,
        },
      };
    }
    return { data };
  },
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```